# Enable 60 second delay on shutdown

Tags: shutdown, xfce, ubuntu-studio

I've just installed Ubuntu Studio 20.04. Previously I had Ubuntu 18.04. Ubuntu Studio does not have the 60 second delay when shutting down, at least by default. How do I get this back?

I didn't see anything in the Xfce Power Manager.

Edit ------------------------------------
/usr/share/doc/acpid/examples/powerbtn.sh
No 'delay' here:

```
#!/bin/sh
# /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh
# Initiates a shutdown when the power putton has been
# pressed.

# getXuser gets the X user belonging to the display in $displaynum.
# If you want the foreground X user, use getXconsole!
getXuser() {
        user=`pinky -fw | awk '{ if ($2 == ":'$displaynum'" || $(NF) == ":'$displaynum'" ) { print $1; exit; } }'`
        if [ x"$user" = x"" ]; then
                startx=`pgrep -n startx`
                if [ x"$startx" != x"" ]; then
                        user=`ps -o user --no-headers $startx`
                fi
        fi
        if [ x"$user" != x"" ]; then
                userhome=`getent passwd $user | cut -d: -f6`
                export XAUTHORITY=$userhome/.Xauthority
        else
                export XAUTHORITY=""
        fi
        export XUSER=$user
}

# Skip if we just in the middle of resuming.
test -f /var/lock/acpisleep && exit 0

# If the current X console user is running a power management daemon that
# handles suspend/resume requests, let them handle policy This is effectively
# the same as 'acpi-support's '/usr/share/acpi-support/policy-funcs' file.

getXconsole
PMS="gnome-power-manager kpowersave xfce4-power-manager"
PMS="$PMS guidance-power-manager.py dalston-power-applet"

if pidof -x $PMS > /dev/null; then
        exit
elif test "$XUSER" != "" && pidof dcopserver > /dev/null && test -x /usr/bin/dcop && /usr/bin/dcop --user $XUSER kded kded loadedModules | grep -q klaptopdaemon; then
        exit
elif test "$XUSER" != "" && test -x /usr/bin/qdbus; then
        kded4pid=$(pgrep -n -u $XUSER kded4)
        if test "$kded4pid" != ""; then
                dbusaddr=$(su - $XUSER -c "grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$kded4pid/environ")
                if test "$dbusaddr" != "" && su - $XUSER -c "export $dbusaddr; qdbus org.kde.kded" | grep -q powerdevil; then
                        exit
                fi
        fi
fi

# If all else failed, just initiate a plain shutdown.
/sbin/shutdown -h now "Power button pressed"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just after some quick research, it seems to be a gnome-shell feature as you listed your shell as Xfce so I looked at why I had it and my current shell and then what was different about your Ubuntu setup and came down to the shell.

"shutdown delay is part of gnome-shell, the timeout is hard-coded somewhere."

Try checking for:

```
/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh
```

Important part:

```
# If the current X console user is running a power management daemon that
# handles suspend/resume requests, let them handle policy This is effectively
# the same as 'acpi-support's '/usr/share/acpi-support/policy-funcs' file.

[ -r /usr/share/acpi-support/power-funcs ] && getXconsole
PMS="gnome-settings-daemon kpowersave xfce4-power-manager"
PMS="$PMS guidance-power-manager.py dalston-power-applet"
PMS="$PMS mate-settings-daemon"
PMS="$PMS unity-settings-daemon"
Your might have more options (I checked 16.04.4 server ) It has several options in the 
to test for different desktops. Assuming you are using systemd: systemd-login uses 
/etc/systemd/logind.conf for its settings.

[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
#UserTasksMax=12288
```

So I would expect this one:

```
InhibitDelayMaxSec=
```

Specifies the maximum time a system shutdown or
sleep request is delayed due to an inhibitor lock of type "delay"
being active before the inhibitor is ignored and the operation
executes anyway. Defaults to 5.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Added to question.